# resources required to run a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

In general, a more complicated neural network(say, an object classification CNN with 128 layers) requires more "resources"(time,number of gpu) to train than a less complicated neural network(for example, an object classification CNN with 32 layers).I found a link which has a very nice summary of different types of CNN and "resources" required to train them:
https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/The-9-Deep-Learning-Papers-You-Need-To-Know-About.html

However, after the training is complete, when we're actually using these neural networks(say, an autonomous driving car using a trained CNN to help navigate the car), do more complicated and more accurate neural networks require more "computational resources"(could be cpu,memory,etc) to run than a less complicated,less accurate neural networks?

I'm asking a generic question and the neural networks are not limited to object classification but can also include neural networks in NLP or other areas.

If the answer is "it depends",can you provide some examples of more complicated, more accurate neural networks using more resources to run than less complicated/accurate neural networks?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the appropriate site for these questions. Please consider visiting [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) for pure machine learning / deep learning questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a recently released CVPR 2017 paper with the title [Speed/accuracy trade-offs for modern convolutional object detectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.10012) (Huang et al.) that compares different feature extractors with some neural network architectures which the authors call "meta-architectures". They compare the so build models towards their speed, memory usage and accuracy.

Comment: I did not down-vote, but I'm quite sure the down-voter did so because link-only answers are discouraged. They become outdated quite soon if the link goes away. I would recommend that you include at least the name of the paper in your answer. So, even if the links does no longer work, you can still find the paper.